# Get correct time since app was closed without network

Tags: flutter

I am creating an idle game (user is rewarded for offline time with ressources). For that calculation I will need the elapsed time since the app was closed.

My first idea was to save the current time when the app is closed and read the current time when the app is opened. But what if a malicious user changes the system time between those actions? The user could get as many ressources as he wants with this trick.

My solution would be to consult a time server to get its current time when closing and opening the app. But this would mean the app would need to be always online, which I am trying to avoid.

Is there any other way I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a lot of ntp servers, you don't need your own

Comment: @DimaRostopira I know that I could use one of the many ntp srvers out there. But that does not fix the 'always online' problem.

Comment: Well, you can use device uptime then, it won't change if user changes date/time in system settings (android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() for example). Yeah, it will be reseted on device reboot, but then user will get less resources, not more

Comment: And yeah, there is flutter plugin for that: https://pub.dev/packages/uptime

Comment: I guess uptime is my best bet to avoid online checks. I saw that I can register for the Shutdown Event. Maybe with this event I could even handle a device reboot. Thanks @DimaRostopira , for the best solution. I would set this as the solution but I guess it is only possible on top level answers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it means that the app always needs to be online. You just take the server time when the user closes the app and you take the time when the user opens the app again. You then subtract the first from the latter and then you have the offline time. Assuming of course that you save the "last_closed" time in a database of some sort.

Comment: Well yes, I would definitly save those timestamps.

But, what if the user is offline at the time of closing the app? Then I could not get the server time. So to prevent this I would need to request the time every x seconds. Which is kind of like always online.

Comment: What do you mean when the user is offline? Do you mean if the user has no network connection? In that case, you can't really have a timestamp that you could rely on anyway, as you couldn't get the server time. Is it possible to require an internet connection for your app?

Comment: It sure is possible, but I am trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

When you are online you read correct time from an api which shows greenwich time not from user's device; so that you always have correct time.